# When the plural subject is used, do I have to take the plural object?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number

I want to say the following contents:

1. There are five users using cell phone.
2. Each of them has to keep a communication link with a base station.
3. That is, the user 1 has to keep a link 'a' with a base station.
4. the user 2 has to keep a link 'b' with a base station.
5. ..., the user 5 also has to keep a link 'e' with a base station.

In this case,

> > The five users should maintain a direct link with the base station.

or

> > The five users should maintain direct links with the base station.

Thank you for reading my question.

Answer (score -1):

The first phrase sentence is ambiguous, because it's not clear whether there's one link for all five users, or five separate links. The second phrase makes it clearer that there are multiple links. You can use the singular, but then you should add a qualifier to make it clear:

> The five users should **each** maintain a direct link with the base station.